# Google Maps not Displaying on Droid, but does on Emulator

Tags: android, google-maps

Ok, so I have my personal google apk that I built from the eclipse I am using.  I know it works because on one of my apps the map displays without issue.  So the problem I am having is this.

When I run my app on the emulator with the debug key, it works no problem.  When I run it on my phone with my key, nothing but the squares.  I know it finds my location because my marker shows up and when tapped it tells me the proper location, just doesn't show the map.  The key is valid (compared to the working app's key to make sure identical) and here is my coding

XML

JAVA

```
mc = mapView.getController();
lat = loc.getLatitude();
lon = loc.getLongitude();
p = new GeoPoint( (int)(lat*1E6), (int)(lon * 1E6));
mc.animateTo(p);
mc.setZoom(20); 

@Override
public void onResume()
{
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000,50, locationListener);
super.onResume();
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you building your APK with the debug or your release key?  If you've used your release key, then you'll need to use the Maps API Key that was created from you release keystore.

Comment: When I do my export, I am using my release key, and with it I am using my API Key (yes, generated from that release key).  As I said before, it works on one app, just not another so not sure where I might have gone wrong.  Thanks for the point though, did double check and rerun, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Is your device connected to the internet? i think the maps are downloaded from the internet, while the coordinates are received by the gps sensor